# Derivative of Trig. Function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, pi

if $f(x)=\tan(3x)$, then $f'(\pi/9)=$?
I thought the answer was $4$ but my teacher marked it wrong. 
Work: $f'(x) = \sec^2(3x)\cdot 3 = \frac 3{\cos^2(3x)} = \frac{3}{\cos^2(\pi/3)} = 3/(3/4) = 4$.

Comment: $\cos(\pi/3) = 1/2$. I think you've instead used the value of $\cos(2\pi/3)$ in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost right, but $\cos \frac{\pi} 3=\frac 1 2$, not $\sqrt{3}\over 2$.

Thus the answer is

$$\frac{3}{\cos^2(\pi/3)} = 3/(1/4) =12$$